# mysql grouping by week

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table with the following fields:

- id
- amount_sale
- the_date (unix timestamp integer)
- payment_type (can be Cash, or Account)

I am trying to create a query that will group all sales by each week of the year, and then split the sum of amount_sales for each week on my page.

Example:

```
week 1 = $26.00  
week 2 = $35.00  
week 3 = $49.00
```

etc.  I'm using this query but it's not working:

```
  SELECT SUM(`amount_sale`) as total 
    FROM `sales` 
   WHERE `payment_type` = 'Account' 
GROUP BY WEEK(`the_date`)
```

Comment: And what error are you getting?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you store `the_date` as integer, you first need to convert it to datetime using `FROM_UNIXTIME` function:

```
 SELECT SUM(`amount_sale`) as total 
FROM `sales` 
WHERE `payment_type` = 'Account' 
GROUP BY WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(`the_date`))
```

**UPDATE**:
Also, you might want to output week number,

```
SELECT CONCAT('Week ', WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(`the_date`))) as week_number,
SUM(`amount_sale`) as total 
FROM `sales` 
WHERE `payment_type` = 'Account' 
GROUP BY WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(`the_date`))
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to also select the weeks in your query, like this:

```
  SELECT SUM(`amount_sale`) as total, WEEK(`the_date`) as week
  FROM `sales` 
  WHERE `payment_type` = 'Account' 
  GROUP BY week ORDER BY week ASC
```

If you have weeks covering several years you could also select the year from `the_date` and order on that as well, like

```
  ORDER BY week ASC, year ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

take your `date` and `get the week`:

```
SELECT DATEPART( wk, getdate())  --this is assuming SQL server
```

and then `group` on that.

Comment: `WEEK()` does the same thing. I believe the problem lies elsewhere. Furthermore, `getdate()` is not a valid MySQL function.

Comment: The question is tagged "MySQL"... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since `the_date` is a unix timestamp, the `WEEK` function won't work.  Instead, you can do this:

> GROUP BY week(FROM_UNIXTIME(the_date))

Keep in mind, this will not perform well, as that function will need to be applied to every row in the table you're querying.