# SQL Query to get data between two weeks?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a week column with week numbers as `w0, w1, w2...`. I am trying to get last last six weeks data. Here's the sql query I am using.

```
SELECT * FROM week 
WHERE uid = '9df984da-4318-1035-9589-493e89385fad'       
  AND report_week BETWEEN `'w52' AND 'w5'`;
```

`'w52'` is essentially week 52 in December 2015 and `'w5'` is Jan 2016. The `'between'` seems to not work. Whats the best way to get data from the above two weeks?

Here's the CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `week` (`uid` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
                     `report_week` VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
                     `report_files_active` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL);
```

Essentially this table is getting populated from other table which has date column. It uses dates from other table and summarizes weekly data into this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you storing the timestamp value in your table?

Comment: Show your table structure. Attach the create table statement of your table.

Comment: between is to replace a combination of "greater than equal AND less than equal" but your condition is just opposite. do you store date in table ?

Comment: I've updated the create table @SubrataDeyPappu

Comment: umm... you don't have date in table? and maybe if you can show me the result that you want

Comment: If you don't store date value then you might get wrong result in overlapping years.

Comment: Why do you store 'w'?

Comment: Store the week numbers as integers instead.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this [SO Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980783/sql-between-clause-with-strings-columns) which details the reasons for a problem similar to yours.

`BETWEEN  'a' and  'b'` actually matches to `columnValue >='a' and columnValue <= 'b'`

In your case **w52** is greater than **w5** due to lexicographic ordering of Strings - this means that the `BETWEEN` clause will never return a true (think about it as equivalent to saying `BETWEEN 10 and 1` instead of `BETWEEN 1 and 10`.

Edit to my response:

Refrain from storing the week value as a string. Instead here are a couple of approaches in order of their preference:

1. Have a timestamp column. You can easily then use MySQL query
   facilities to extract the week information out of this. For a
   reference see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710342/mysql-grouping-by-week) post.
2. Maintain two columns - `YEAR, WEEKNO` where `YEAR` will store values
   like **2015, 2016** etc and `WEEKNO` will store the week number.
   This way you can query data for any week in any year.

Answer (score 0):

please show me table structure and DB name because it different for other, if it is any timestamp then we can use BETWEEN `'systemdate' AND 'systemdate-6'`