# datatables dates at the top and data cells going from left to right

Tags: php, html, database, datatables

I am working on a system that caters services for small groups of registered members based on their locations (cells). The current issue I am having is displaying a list of services against the count of those present on a particular date.
The query is correct but I am having issues formatting the table correctly

the data should display as so

SERVICE | DATE1 | DATE2 | etc

---

HEALTH | 5 | 3 | etc

---

DENTIST | 10 | 20 | etc

This is currently what I have done:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">         
                <div class="box-body no-padding">
                        <table class="table cell-border" id="members">
                            <thead>
                                <th>Service</th>
                                    <?php foreach($result as $g){?>
                                            <th><?php echo $g['date'];?></th>
                                    <?php }?>

                            </thead>
                            <tbody> 
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $g['Service Name'];?></td>
                                    <?php $i=1; foreach($result as $g){ ?>
                                    <td> <?php if($g['Attendance'] == 'NULL') {echo 0;} else { echo $g['Attendance'];}?> </td>
                                    <?php }?>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </div>
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT record_attendance_cell.id, record_attendance_cell.`company_id`,record_attendance_cell.`cell_id`,record_attendance_cell.`member_id`, COUNT(record_attendance_cell.`present`) as `Attendance`, record_attendance_cell.`service_id`,record_attendance_cell.`date`, setting_company.name `Company Name`, setting_cell_group.`location`, `setting_service`.title as `Service Name`
FROM `record_attendance_cell`
LEFT JOIN setting_company
on setting_company.id = record_attendance_cell.company_id
LEFT JOIN setting_cell_group
on setting_cell_group.id = record_attendance_cell.cell_id
LEFT JOIN setting_service
on setting_service.id = record_attendance_cell.service_id
WHERE record_attendance_cell.`present` = 1 AND record_attendance_cell.`date` BETWEEN '$date_from' AND '$date_to'
group by record_attendance_cell.service_id
order by record_attendance_cell.date asc
```

Comment: "The query is correct but I am having issues formatting the table correctly" What is correctly and what you get now?

Comment: this is the result of the query

https://ibb.co/bTFVvQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your result and your description. I have come up with this:

Please give it a try (EDITED):

```
<style>
    table th, table td {
        border: 1px solid #333;
    }
</style>
<?php
$result[] = array('Service Name' => 'Health', 'date' => '2017-04-04', 'Attendance' => 5);
$result[] = array('Service Name' => 'Payroll', 'date' => '2017-04-16', 'Attendance' => 5);
$result[] = array('Service Name' => 'Saturday Youth Meeting', 'date' => '2017-04-03', 'Attendance' => 1);
$result[] = array('Service Name' => 'Saturday Youth Meeting', 'date' => '2017-05-03', 'Attendance' => 3);
$result[] = array('Service Name' => 'Payroll', 'date' => '2017-05-03', 'Attendance' => 2);
$result[] = array('Service Name' => 'Payroll', 'date' => '2017-04-11', 'Attendance' => 3);

foreach ($result as $row) {
    $array[$row['Service Name']][$row['date']] = $row;
}

$start_date = '2017-04-03';
$end_date = '2017-05-03';
echo '<table><thead><tr><th>Service</th>';

$date = $start_date;
WHILE (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    echo '<th>' . $date . '</th>';
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . ' +1day'));
}
echo '</tr></thead>';
echo '<tbody>';

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $date = $start_date;
    echo '<tr><td>'.$key.'</td>';
    WHILE (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
        if (array_key_exists($date, $array[$key])) {
            echo '<td>' . $array[$key][$date]['Attendance'] . '</td>';
        } else {
            echo '<td>0</td>';
        }
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . ' +1day'));
    }
        echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</tbody></table>';
```

OUTPUT:

http://www.phpwin.org/s/ewbAS6

If you want the attendance to be accumulative, simply change the WHILE loop (ADDED)

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $array[$row['Service Name']][$row['date']] = $row;
}

$start_date = '2017-04-03';
$end_date = '2017-05-03';
echo '<table><thead><tr><th>Service</th>';

$date = $start_date;
WHILE (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    echo '<th>' . $date . '</th>';
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . ' +1day'));
}
echo '</tr></thead>';
echo '<tbody>';

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $date = $start_date;
    echo '<tr><td>'.$key.'</td>';
    $attendance = 0;
    WHILE (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
        if (array_key_exists($date, $array[$key])) {
            $attendance = $attendance + $array[$key][$date]['Attendance'];
        }
        echo '<td>' . $attendance .'</td>';
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . ' +1day'));
    }
        echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</tbody></table>';
```

OUTPUT

http://www.phpwin.org/s/5umFBA

Comment: The dates at the top is meant to be an interation of dates in between the search. for example you search between 2017-01-01 and 2017-05-01 it should have every result from each date. Each date will be shown in the TH and each count value for each service should be correctly alligned in the TD.

Comment: Hi +1 for the answer it seems to be working well, just had to adjust the time period from +1day to 1+week.

Comment: There is a small issue that the data displayed in the table only shows when the date matches that in the interation.

For example if I have an attendance of 5 on wednesday the 3/10/2017 and an attendance of 12 on thursday the 4/10/2017 and the looped header is 7/10/2017, the column will say 0 , but it should be at least 17 because it should aggregate from the previous days.

I have tried using mysql and using the date function to group the data into year, month and week but still having the issues. Any Idea?

Comment: Next time please well prepare your question with your desired output. Your "small issue" is completely different from your original question. Please check my answer for updated script

Comment: Michael your initial solution is correct it should echo 0 when there is no value for the DAY but I need it to sum for the WEEK. 
Your new one is just aggregation of data for each date when the iteration is per day but when you change it to per week the values do not add up. Let me show you a screenshot

https://ibb.co/kb3sFQ

I hope you understand me better now? Sorry for the confusion

Comment: You will have to create a new post with better question and more organized data. Suggest you to make a better query first. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710342/mysql-grouping-by-week