# Grouping data to get reports by intervals

Tags: php, mysql, date, datatable

I posted a question some time ago on representing data per date horizontally on a datatable.
See here: [datatables dates at the top and data cells going from left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267138/datatables-dates-at-the-top-and-data-cells-going-from-left-to-right)

With the help of that thread I was able to get the data to display how I wanted it. With the dates showing at the top, the service provided on the left and all data associated with any date between the 2 date paramters inside the main body. (If there is no data in a particular date then the < td >  will display 0. See here:
http://www.phpwin.org/s/ewbAS6

After manipulating this code further I made the dates of the search dynamic by proving a form with a start date and an end date, and a dropdown with the options of:

1. Daily
2. Weekly
3. Monthly
4. Quaterly
5. Yearly

this allows the interval of dates at the top to become dynamic. Of course all this is doing is changing the value of the 2nd parameter inside the date while loop.

```
WHILE (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    echo '<th>' . $date . '</th>';
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . ' +1day'));
}
```

with the parameter set at Weekly, the value of +1day becomes +1week, at Monthly; the value becomes +1month and so on.

MY ISSUE:

When the interval is set to daily, the dates with their corresponding attendance counts are displayed correctly but once you try to increase the interval to +1week and above the data does not round up to the week shown. Check this:

[LINK1]Per day: http://www.phpwin.org/s/ewbAS6

[LINK2]Per month: http://www.phpwin.org/s/xRo3I6

Looking at the array (modified on the LINK2)

```
$result[] = array('Service Name' => 'Health', 'date' => '2017-04-04', 'Attendance' => 5);
$result[] = array('Service Name' => 'Payroll', 'date' => '2017-04-16', 'Attendance' => 5);
$result[] = array('Service Name' => 'Saturday Youth Meeting', 'date' => '2017-04-03', 'Attendance' => 1);
$result[] = array('Service Name' => 'Saturday Youth Meeting', 'date' => '2017-05-03', 'Attendance' => 3);
$result[] = array('Service Name' => 'Payroll', 'date' => '2017-05-03', 'Attendance' => 2);
$result[] = array('Service Name' => 'Payroll', 'date' => '2017-04-11', 'Attendance' => 3);
$result[] = array('Service Name' => 'Payroll', 'date' => '2018-04-03', 'Attendance' => 10);
```

You can see in the array that there are multiple attendance entries in April, totaling 14 Attendances in that month however during LINK2 where the interval is increased to a month instead of showing 14 for April (which would be the sum of all the dates in that particular month) it shows the value 1.

My live version takes the array from a database so I used the YEAR(), MONTH(), WEEK() and DAY() function on the date and used group by. The query executes how I want it but having issues working on the PHP end.

Comment: Why not use the pivot table technique in the SQL statement? Generating the SQL statement in php based on the date range and range type (?) would be pretty simple, and then the output would be trivial. Your output (headings and totals) would be simple stepping through the results of the SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks was a step in the right direction, i've been trying it with not as much luck as I would have hoped but I think this is easier than manipulating the data presentation from php