# how to create a view with output grouped by calendar week

Tags: html, mysql, codeigniter

My database table is

| id | kecamatan | tanggal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA | 02-01-2022 |
| 2 | AB | 03-01-2022 |
| 3 | AA | 10-01-2022 |
| 4 | AB | 12-01-2022 |
| 5 | AA | 17-01-2022 |
| 6 | AC | 18-01-2022 |

I want this result, because I can not replace other structure

| id | kecamatan | 202202 | 202203 | 202204 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA | 02-01-2022 | 10-01-2022 | 17-01-2022 |
| 2 | AB | 03-01-2022 | 12-01-2022 |  |
| 3 | AC |  |  | 18-01-2022 |

FAQ :
202202,202203,202204 is grouping query by week

Comment: what is the logic behind your desired output? 1st I thought 202201 is the 1st *tanggal*, etc. but AC's 1st is in *202203*, why?  can you please edit your question to make this more clear? ohhh... calendar week?

Comment: 202201,202202,202203 is grouping query by week.. Tanks vickel

Comment: please have a look into mysql WEEK function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week. translate the dates into a week number and query from there and: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6710398/2275490